# Replacing in Ruby on Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, special-characters, ampersand

I have an excel input file like this.

```
Artist
A & B
C
```

Here "Artist" is the column header.

The ruby on rails program has this code:

```
artist_keys = @params.keys.select{|k| k =~ /^artist/i}
@artists = []
artist_keys.each do |artist_key|
  @artists.push @params[artist_key].to_s.encode('utF-8')
end
```

I want to store "A %26 B", instead of "A & B" in the "artist_key(s)" or "artist(s)" variable.

I tried channging "A & B" to "A %26 B" in the xlsx input file. But then the program faced an error.

So I think this "replace & with %26" should be done by code-level rather than inputfile-level.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to store it that way? If you have a particular output in mind, do it at output time rather when stored.

Comment: @MarkThomas Because the variable "artist" will be used to search Youtube API gdata. & has a special meaning in gdata, so gdata doesn't think "&" is a part of artist name.

Comment: As @MarkThomas said, *do it at output time*. In your case, encode it when you use it to search Youtube API gdata, with the help of `uri` lib: `URI.encode('A & B', '&')`

Comment: You can also use `CGI.escape('A & B')` which will result in `A+%26+B` - which URI-safe data

Comment: @ArieShaw Thank you. I tried to do it at output time, but actually I couldn't get where exactly the code for the output time is.  So I proceeded with Micah's solution, and it worked. I will try to find out the "output time" solution when I get some more time.

Comment: @MarkThomas   Thank you. I tried to do it at output time, but actually I couldn't get where exactly the code for the output time is. So I proceeded with Micah's solution, and it worked. I will try to find out the "output time" solution when I get some more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned doing it at output time would be the "best" solution but if you really want to simply find and replace, gsub is your answer.

```
artist_keys.each do |artist_key|
  @artists.push @params[artist_key].to_s.gsub('&','%26').encode('utF-8')
end
```

However I would not recommend storing like that if at all possible.